# Throttle actions taken by repeated calls to an API endpoint - ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, throttling

I have an external service notification hitting an endpoint when there has been a change in my database. This pulls the updated data from the database and fires it out to connected clients via SignalR.

This service can send multiple calls within the span of a few seconds, but I'd like to only respond to the final one. I'd like to throttle (not sure if that's the right word in this case) the calls to the database and notifications to the client. The important part here is I'd like to respond to the FINAL request withing a timeframe as I don't want to miss any changes sent to clients.

Here's an example of the problem I'd like to avoid. This is a log of hits to the API ending in a deadlock error (I can handle that, but would like to avoid the whole situation altogether).

```
RefreshOrderNotifications received at Tue Oct 03 2023 09:34:19 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
RefreshOrderNotifications received at Tue Oct 03 2023 09:34:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
RefreshOrderNotifications received at Tue Oct 03 2023 09:34:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
RefreshOrderNotifications received at Tue Oct 03 2023 09:34:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
Server - Error: Notification Server connection to DB failed. Transaction (Process ID 68) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how to approach this problem.  As each request is on a different thread, I'm not quite sure how to communicate across those threads. Would a static property even be useful or wise in this case? I'm not sure if it's shared across threads.

I can stand to have a 1-3 second delay in the response to the API call, if that's helpful.

Adding clarification based on comments (All good questions, thank you)

- There is no payload to process in the API call other than to query the SQL server and send off notifications via SignalR.
- In the endpoint call, the caller doesn't get anything back other than an empty 200 OK.  The caller just wants to kick off a notification.
- The call sends off a notification to the connected clients.
- I'm trying to avoid unnecessary messages to the clients and hits to the DB.  I'd like to simply discard the first calls, then send a notification off for the perceived last one.

Second edit:
Based on the really helpful response from @qkhanhpro, I put this together.  It has some holes as the actions aren't atomic (I believe that's how you refer to it), so if there is a quick succession of calls at the same time, then they will slip by.  This is as good as I need for now.  I'll clean it up and do some further testing.

```
 public class ThrottleManager
{
    private List<string> _queue = new List<string>();

    public async Task<ThrottleResult> QueueThenRun(string runKey, int delayMilliseconds, Func<Task<ThrottleResult>> funcToRun)
    {
        var result = new ThrottleResult();

        if (_queue.Contains(runKey) || funcToRun == null)
        {           
            //we're just queuing up the call, so return success
            return result;
        }
        _queue.Add(runKey);

        await Task.Delay(delayMilliseconds);
        _queue.Remove(runKey);

        var returnMe = await funcToRun();
        return returnMe;
    }
}

public class ThrottleResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Exception? Exception { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to throttle calls to the API itself or throttle calls internally to your resources? Those are two different things. Generally, throttling, windowing, and rate limiting are roughly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @kit, great question.  I'm looking to throttle DB calls and updates to the client.

So, API gets called say 4 times in a second, pull from DB and update to client happens with the last call.

One thing I'm reading about at a friend's recommendation is the Outbox Pattern.  So far I understand it's a message queue that I process.  Just trying to figure out if that'll sort me out, and not be too heavy.

Comment: You need to clarify more the idea. You said would like to "respond" to the final request only. But do you want to process all request payloads or only the last request payload? Do you want to discard the "early" requests completely or you would like to actually "batching" a few requests together and process all of them?.

Comment: @qkhanhpro, I edited the post, hopefully answering your questions.  Thank you for taking the time out to read the question.

Comment: Hello, have you tired the solution and suggestion provided? Do you still have any concern on this? Please let us know if you need any further assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a singleton class that hold a single ConcurrentDictionary. The "Key" would be the criteria you would like to "group" by, such as the `OrderId` or `UserId`, the Value should be a `Task`

Whenever a request/thread hit you

- Try to see if the Key-Value pair exists
- If the Key exits, await the corresponding Task
- If the Key does not exists, create the Key-Value pair and start the Task
- The Task should incorporate a small wait time using Task.Delay()
- The Task, after its delay should do its processing, and remove the Key-Value pair from ConcurrentDictionary as it finish

Comment: *create a singleton class that hold a single ConcurrentDictionary* won't work over a cluster of separate processes (e.g. multiple servers).

Comment: That is indeed correct @WiktorZychla . That part, and the direct subscription to existing task on memory, while having the benefit of simplicity, would behave as expected only on non clustered environment

Comment: @qkhanhpro thank you for this.  This is really the best bet for me. Wiktor, I appreciate the clarification, but in my particular case I'm just looking to minimize the calls, not put a complete stop to them.  This is currently not load balanced, but even if we go there, this solution should do the trick for me.

I'll try to implement this in a few days and comment on the findings.

Comment: @qkhanhpro I was able to get this working and edited my question above to include my implementation.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is generally known as *request deduplication*.

You can achieve that with [ThrottlingTroll's SemaphoreRateLimitMethod](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-rate-limiting-algorithms).

Configure [ThrottlingTroll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ThrottlingTroll#readme-body-tab) like this:

```
app.UseThrottlingTroll(options =>
{
    options.Config = new ThrottlingTrollConfig
    {
        Rules = new[]
        {
            new ThrottlingTrollRule
            {
                // Organizing a distributed critical section (one request allowed at a time)
                LimitMethod = new SemaphoreRateLimitMethod
                {
                    PermitLimit = 1
                }
            }
        }
    };

    options.ResponseFabric = async (check, request, response, token) =>
    {
        // Shortcutting extra requests to 200 status code and empty response
        response.StatusCode = 200;
    };
});
```

This will put a *distributed critical section* on top of your endpoint - only one request will be allowed at a time, the rest will be dismissed with 200 status code.

Then put an `await Task.Delay(numOfMilliseconds);` line *in front of* your API method. While the first request sleeps at that line, other unwanted ones are dismissed by ThrottlingTroll. Then the first request resumes and does the job.

And yes, by adding a [Redis Counter Store](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.CounterStores.Redis) you can make this truly distributed - it will behave as expected even across multiple computing instances.

And yes, they now require me to explicitly state that ThrottlingTroll is *my* library.

Comment: Please state in your answer that ThrottlingTroll is your library - otherwise your post is liable to be deleted as spam/undisclosed self-promotion.